# Delete duplicate number in text cell (Teradata database)

Tags: sql, teradata

I have columns in which coordinates are presented in the text format. Each set of coordinates in one cell. All coordinates all coordinates are in one table cell, like text. And i have more than 1000 cells and each contains more than 100 coordinates.

For example:

23.453411011874813 41.74245395132344, 23.453972640029299 41.74214208390741, 23.453977029220994 41.741827739090233, 23.454523642352295 41.741515869012523, 23.441100249526403 41.741203996333724, **23.441661846243466 41.740892121053918**,
*23.456223434003668 41.74058024317317*, **23.441661846243466 41.740892121053918**

In the case of repeating coordinates, I need to delete the last of them (bold in the example) and delete the coordinate located between them (italic in the example).

Please tell me how this can be done?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is that one or several rows of data? How many columns?

Comment: update your question and add  the related  table schema  ..

Comment: I'd probably start by splitting the coordinates (pairs of values) into separate rows with a sequence number, e.g. using STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_TABLE. But what happens if a coordinate appears more than twice?

Comment: Аll coordinates are in one table cell

Answer (score 0):

OLAP functions will be your friend.
 - ROW_NUMBER() will identify the 2nd, 3rd,... occurences
 - with COUNT() OLAP you can identify the double ones
 - with CASE and some MAX-ROWS PRECEEDING you can tag the rows between 1st and 2nd

Two crucial questions for the concrete solution, you have to ask:
 - by which criteria are your rows ordered (I guess a not shown column with TimeStamps...)
 - what happens if a coordinate occurs 3 -times (or even more)? - Delete all between 1st and last or just between 1st and 2nd or always between uneven&even?